# Inequality that discribe Half space in front of space

Tags: 3d

> The inequality that discribes the Half space of set of points in front of $yz$ plane is

What i try::

The inequality that discribe the Half space of set of points is $$x\geq 0$$.

Please tell me is i am right or wrong.

If wrong plesse tell me correct answer. Thanks

Comment: What does "in front of" mean? In the right-hand-rule convention with right thumb = positive x axis, index finger = positive y, middle finger = positive z, then your answer is correct

Comment: Thanks Elliot for your visulization. I have one doubt. Why i am include $x=0$ . Why we can not say $x>0$